# Does the ring of regular expressions exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, formal-languages

It is well known that the set of Regular Expressions R over some alphabet form a semiring with:

- Concatenation as multiplication
- The empty string as the multiplicative identity
- 'Or' as addition
- The empty set of strings as the additive identity

**Q**. Does there exist an extension of R to a ring?

Comment: Yes, but it's the zero ring. Union is idempotent, so every element satisfies $a + a = a$. In a ring this implies $a = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. So that extension is therefore unique, right (i.e. it implies that no other extensions can exist)?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean by "extension." There's a universal map from any semiring to a ring, namely the ring given by adjoining additive inverses to every element. In this case that ring and that map are zero.

Comment: 'Extension' = 'alternative mapping'. In other words, is the zero ring the only ring that can be constructed from REs (given the above definition)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "constructed from." In this case, the only semiring homomorphism from the semiring above to a ring is the homomorphism to the zero ring, because the zero ring doesn't admit homomorphisms to any nonzero rings. In general there will be many such homomorphisms, for example quotients of the universal one.

Comment: Do you mean regular expressions or regular languages? If you insist to work on regular expressions, please give a formal definition.

Comment: I'd be happy to consider Regular Languages with '+' as choice, '*' as sequencing. I assume '-' would have to be complement, but maybe the latter begs the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular languages on an alphabet $A$ form a semiring with union as addition (and the empty set as $0$) and concatenation product as product (and the language reduced to the empty word as $1$). This semiring is noncommutative if and only if $|A| > 1$.

This semiring can be identified with the [semiring of rational series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_series) over the Boolean semiring $\mathbb{B} = \{0, 1\}$. As a set, this semiring can be embedded into the ring of rational series over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, but this embedding is not a semiring embedding since in $\mathbb{B}$, $1 + 1 = 1$.
A very good reference on this topic is [1].

[1] J. Berstel and C. Reutenauer, *Noncommutative rational series with applications*, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications, 137. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2011. xiv+248 pp. ISBN 978-0-521-19022-0

Answer (score 3):

The zero element is the empty set (i.e., empty language) and the unit element contains as its sole element the empty string.
A ring requires to have an additive inverse for each element. But this is not the case when the operation is union of languages (i.e., union as sets).